# Kafka config replica.fetch.max.bytes on a per-topic level

Tags: apache-kafka

I would like to set a Kafka cluster to only allow large messages on a particular topic.  From the [docs](https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation.html#brokerconfigs) I see that if I wanted to do this at the level of the entire cluster I could do so by setting `message.max.bytes` to allow a larger amount of data on the broker and `replica.fetch.max.bytes` to allow it to be replicated, but my understanding is that this would increase memory usage for all topics in my cluster, not just the one that I know can receive large messages.  There is also a topic-level setting `max.message.bytes` that controls the maximum size of messages, but I don't see a topic-level setting controlling the maximum data size of replication operations.  It seems strange that one of these closely tied settings is not configurable at a topic level; perhaps I'm missing where such setting is or there is another way to accomplish these goals?

Answer (score 2):

`replica.fetch.max.bytes` can only be set on the broker level. However, you can set `max.partition.fetch.bytes` on the consumer side:

> The maximum amount of data per-partition the server will return.
>   Records are fetched in batches by the consumer. If the first record
>   batch in the first non-empty partition of the fetch is larger than
>   this limit, the batch will still be returned to ensure that the
>   consumer can make progress. The maximum record batch size accepted by
>   the broker is defined via message.max.bytes (broker config) or
>   max.message.bytes (topic config). See fetch.max.bytes for limiting the
>   consumer request size.

Note that this is a per-partition configuration, meaning that if you set it to a large number, it will consume a lot of memory in case you have a lot of partitions too.

Comment: Yes, but `replica.fetch.max.bytes` has to be set for Kafka's guarantees of resilience in the event of broker failure to hold, correct?  So effectively it sounds like this setting being at the broker level nullifies `max.message.bytes` for users who care about resilience.